# iOS getting reference to a specific autolayout constraint added in Interface Builder in code

Tags: ios, autolayout

Say I worked with autolayout all in Interface Builder, then in my code, in respond to a certain event, I need to modify just one specific constraint (in my case, a constraint about the height), for now I can only use `removeConstraints:` to remove all constraints then add them one by one in code.

Is it possible to get a reference to a specific constraint I added in Interface Builder? that would make life easier I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Open the assistant editor, find the specific constraint you want in IB, and then option-drag it to the VC to create a named property.

You can now programmatically reference self.myConstraint!

Comment: Thanks, the question seemed silly but before your answer I've been worked like what I described!